# How to add an image and increment the images on after each onclick function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to dynamically take images from my images folder in my project. With the click function, I need the first image to show in the div, clicking the same button should add a second button, and so forth, on reaching the last image it should start back at the top and continue adding the images until reset is clicked. I need to have a counter that will keep showing the total number of images.

I'm not able to move past getting the images to show. I've added them in an array to bypass the issue of the various names as renaming them is not an option. Currently, the images do not show up and I get the little icons for missing images and twelve icons at once, not one at a time.

Below is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#add_cat").click(function(){
    let images = [];
    images[0] = '<img src="../images/abyssinian-cat_small.jpg">';
    images[1] = '<img src="/images/birman-cat_small.jpg">';
    images[2] = '<img src="/images/british-shorhair_small.jpg">';
    images[3] = '<img src="/images/maine-coon_small.jpg">';
    images[4] = '<img src="/images/persian-cat_small.jpg">';
    images[5] = '<img src="/images/ragdoll-cat_small.jpg">';
    images[6] = '<img src="/images/russian-blue_small.jpg">';
    images[7] = '<img src="/images/savannah-cat_small.jpg">';
    images[8] = '<img src="/images/scottish-fold_small.jpg">';
    images[9] = '<img src="/images/siamese-cat_small.jpg">';
    images[10] = '<img src="/images/singapura-cat_small.jpg">';
    images[11] = '<img src="/images/sphynx-cat_small.jpg">';

    for (var i=1; i<=images.length; i++)
    {
        $("#cats").prepend('<img src="images/'+i+'.jpg">');
    }

})
```

})

Comment: when you mouse over the missing icon it should show the URL which may help with debugging

Comment: It's showing the right path, not sure why the image won't load.  I've tried changing the type of quote I'm using to see if that helps

Comment: Try visiting the links. If you get a 404 try clearing your cache. If you still get a 404 try clearing your DNS cache.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your code is not correct

```
for (var i=1; i<=images.length; i++)
{
    $("#cats").prepend('<img src="images/'+i+'.jpg">');
}
```

Should be

```
for (var i=1; i<=images.length; i++)
{
    $("#cats").prepend(images[i]);
}
```

Second, the better way to do this is to add all the images right in the HTML (or javascript if you must) and then hide them all, showing them one at a time. The advantage of this is that you know the images are there, so it's only a question of getting the show/hide logic right

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this helped to show the right path of the file, but the images still do not load.